# Can't deploy to raspberry pi, windows iot

Tags: visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I can no longer deploy my app to windows IoT for debugging (Raspberry Pi 3) using Visual Studio 2015. Yesterday everything was OK, today I get the error:

DEP6956 : Failed to establish connection to the device due to protocol incompatibility. Please try again, and if this error persists, please try restarting the target device. Device supports protocol 'Sirep2'.

I've tried setting the endpoint to both the IP address and the device name. I'm using the latest insider preview version of windows IoT.

I can still connect to the device using the App Manager in a browser, and also using IoT dashboard.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 6):

I've had issues with this as well if I've disconnected or restarted the Pi while Visual Studio has remained open. As a best practice I'd suggest always starting or restarting Visual Studio after every Pi restart. To further clarify this only seems to affect an instance of Visual Studio that was previously connected to the device or previously involved in a remote deployment. Other instances of VS should be fine.

This is of course time consuming and shouldn't need to happen but avoids the deployment errors mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, three reboots later of the Raspberry PI, Visual Studio and the laptop, it is working again. I don't know what the problem was, but all is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading Windows IoT Core through the dashboard is all that worked for me.